# Как добавить еще одно значение к ключу для localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Допустим у меня есть два инпута. Первый инпут для ввода названия, второй текст для отзыва к данному товару и должна быть кнопка который сохраняет отзыв в localStorage.
Как лучше сделать так, что-бы при наличие товаров на странице к ним добавлялись отзывы которые были введены в инпут.
Можно без кода, просто направьте на путь истинный)

Comment: Как вариант - хранить объект, где ключами будет название товара (это же строка), а значением будет массив отзывов.

Answer (score 0):

> Как лучше сделать так, что-бы при наличие товаров на странице к ним добавлялись отзывы которые были введены в инпут.

Например вот так можно сделать...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-theme='light'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
    let obj = localStorage.getItem('obj') 
    obj = obj || '{}'
    obj = JSON.parse(obj)
    const oi = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li')
    oi.forEach(o => {
        const ol = document.createElement('ol')
        o.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', ol)
        const v = o.querySelector('span').textContent
        obj[v]?.forEach(t => {
            ol.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${t}</li>`)
        })
    })
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const k = item.value
        const t = text.value
        if (k == '' || t == '') return
        obj[k] = obj[k] ?? []
        obj[k].push(t)
        localStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj)) 
        e.target.reset()
        oi.forEach(o => {
            const v = o.querySelector('span').textContent
            if (v != k) return
            o.querySelector('ol').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${t}</li>`)
        })
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label>
        <span>Товар</span>
        <input id='item' />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Комментарий</span>
        <input id='text' />
    </label>
    <button>Добавить</button>
</form>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Картошка</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Лук</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```